# IO.Filestream upload file individual file errors with invalid characters from the path

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, upload, document

I have a problem with a bulk upload script I am working on to upload multiple files with metadata, referenced in a CSV, to SharePoint 2013.

My script runs fine until the `Upload()` function is called and then errors at the point where the `IO.StreamFile` opens the file with the error "invalid characters". This is because (I believe) the `StreamFile` just wants the document name, but I am passing the entire file path and name.

I am stuck as to how to get the `StreamFile` to recognize the file and continue to upload it from its dir path, as each document will reside in a different directory and be uploaded to a different library. I have simplified the code below.

```cs
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Add-Type -Path ([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client").Location)
Add-Type -Path ([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.runtime").Location)

function UploadFile($DestinationFolder, $doc) {
    #Get the datastream of the file, assign it to a variable
    $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($doc.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
    #Create an instance of a FileCreationInformation object
    $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
    #Indicate whether or not you would like to overwrite files in the event of a conflict
    $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $True
    #Make the datastream of the file you wish to create equal to the datastream of the source file 
    $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream 
    #Make the URL of the file equal to the $File variable which was passed to the function.  This will be equal to the source file name
    $FileCreationInfo.url = $doc
    #Add the file to the destination folder which was passed to the function, using the FileCreationInformation supplied.  Assign this to a variable so that it can be loaded into context.
    $Upload = $DestinationFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
    #Set metadata properties
    $listItem = $Upload.ListItemAllFields
    #Adds member number as meta data in the library against the file
    $listItem["MemberNumber"] = $MemberNumber
    $listItem.Update()
    $Context.Load($Upload)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}

$GroupSite= "http://Contoso:1985/sites/group1"
$UserName = "contoso/admin"
$Password = "Password"
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($GroupSite)
$Creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($UserName, (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

$src = "D:\Import\CSVs\group1.csv"
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($src)
$header = Get-Content -Path $src | select -First 1
while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    #Set metadata
    $data = $line -split ','
    $PersonID = $data[14]
    #This is the column in the CSV that gives the file directory path to the file
    $File = $data[17]
    $FileName = $File .Substring($File .LastIndexOf("\")+1)
    $FileExists = Test-Path $File
    # if document doesnt exist log it:
    if ($FileExists -eq $false) {
        Write-Host "$FileName Document Doesnt Exist!" -ForegroundColor Green
    } else {
        $MemberNumber = $data[0]
        $List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($PersonID)
        $Context.Load($List)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        #Get the document/file  
        $ActualFile = Get-Item -Path $File
        foreach ($doc in ($ActualFile)) {
            Write-Host "Uploading file " $doc.Name "to" $PersonID -ForegroundColor Cyan
            UploadFile($list.RootFolder) $doc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing what it is that you're passing, exactly what the error it and exactly on what part it occurs.... how do you want anyone to be able to help you at all? That's like going to a doctor and saying "hey, I think there's something wrong with me, can you tell me what's wrong?"

Comment: You are absolutely correct! i apologize for not being clear enough. I have now edited to original post to try to be clearer and i have simplified the code so that if i am not clear enough in my description an expert may be able to see from the code where the problem lies.

Comment: Please show the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for your really helpful comments, I have fixed the script.

Comment: Regardless of the fact that you've fixed your script on your own, the above comment still stands. Also, if you did fix the script it would be helpful to others if you posted an answer to your own questions where you outline the difference in code and how you arrived at the solution.